# Cant install my app on other phones

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, apk

I made an android app with eclipse, which I can debug normally on my phone. Also I can install the signed apk of the app normally.

But if I send this apk to friends, they can't install them, with the german errors: `"Datei kann nicht geöffnet werden"` or `"anwendung für diese Aktion kann nicht gefunden werden"`, translated: `"could not open file"` and `"could not find app for this action"`.

I don't know what's wrong.

I plugged in one of these phones and grabbed the error with logcat:

> W/DownloadManager(12940): Failed to start Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=content://downloads/all_downloads/96 typ=application/octet-stream
>   flg=0x3 }: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity
>   found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=content://downloads/all_downloads/96 typ=application/octet-stream
>   flg=0x3 }

Oddly, I can debug the app on the phone without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Their phones may not support the APIs you have used. Use a lower version of the API and try again if the app isn't that big.

Comment: they have the same android version like me: 4.4.4
and the app has:android:minSdkVersion="13"

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. And the `adb install` command solved it. 
So what I think is the issue here is that the phone is not using the native software for opening files/links - for example a colleague had a problem because the Facebook app was the device's default for opening downloaded files (with URI like `content://downloads/all_downloads/...`).
Also, you will find that the Firefox app faced the [same issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1070099).